# Pandas str.extract() regex to extract city info

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas df of addresses like this:

```
df['address']

0. ALL that certain piece, parcel or tract of land situate, lying and being in the City 
   of Travelers Rest, County of Greenville, State of South Carolina

1. Townes Street on the West, in the City of Greenville, County of Greenville, State of 
   South Carolina

2. State of South Carolina, County of Greenville, City of Hampton on the southern side
```

I want to extract the name of `city` such that expected results:

```
Travelers Rest
Greenville
Hampton
```

My code is below:

```
df['city'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'\b(?:City of?) (.+?(?=[,]))')
```

My results:

```
Travelers Rest
Greenville
City of Hampton on the...
```

However, when the city name doesn't end with a `,` it will pick up the rest of the string. If i don't end my regex in `,` I won't get the full city name in some cases. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Might be a bit tricky to find city-names as usually is the case with names. However, if you can confidently say names are always starting uppercase and are concatenated with a space or hyphen, then try: `\bCity\s+of\s+([A-Z][a-z]+(?:[- ][A-Z][a-z]+)*)`. Needless to say, this will go bust when you have citynames like `Andorra la Vella`, `St. Louis`, `Stoke-on-Trent` and even strange names like [`Saint-Louis-du-Ha! Ha!`](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Saint-Louis-du-Ha!_Ha!) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for the example data could be matching the following words starting with a capital A-Z and optional non whitespace chars excluding a comma:

```
\bCity\s+of\s+([A-Z][^\s,]+(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s,]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/roxrWu/1)

```
data = [
    "ALL that certain piece, parcel or tract of land situate, lying and being in the City   of Travelers Rest, County of Greenville, State of South Carolina",
    "Townes Street on the West, in the City of Greenville, County of Greenville, State of South Carolina",
    "State of South Carolina, County of Greenville, City of Hampton on the southern side"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["address"])
df["city"] = df["address"].str.extract(r"\bCity\s+of\s+([A-Z][^\s,]+(?:\s+[A-Z][^\s,]+)*)")
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                             address            city
0  ALL that certain piece, parcel or tract of lan...  Travelers Rest
1  Townes Street on the West, in the City of Gree...      Greenville
2  State of South Carolina, County of Greenville,...         Hampton
```